# Is assigning a value directly to javascript module error property bad form?

Tags: object, error-handling, module, literals

I'm converting a bunch of straight spaghetti code jQuery event handlers to Object Literal Modules ( still learning ).
I can't seem to use error with 'this' to update it's value.
I was wondering if using the module name itself is bad form and or ok?
For instance:

```js
var = moduleName {
  error: false,
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$someElement = $( 'someElement' );
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.$someElement.on( 'someEvent', this.someFunction.bind( this );
    },
    updateErrorLevel: function() {
        // this.error = true;       // << fails
        // this.event.error = true; // << fails        
        moduleName.error = true;    // << works 
    },
    someFunction: function( event ) {
        this.updateErrorLevel.call();
    }
};
 
moduleName.init();
```

Any ideas where or if I'm going wrong here?
All suggestions welcome and greatly appreciated.